# While upgrading to jdk7 to jdk11 with wildfly16 drools are not working

Tags: drools, java-11

Hi I am having following configuration:

```
java version-jdk11
server-wildfly16
jars-drools 6.0 and ecj 4.6.1
```

in server location: `C:\wildfly-16.0.0.Final\modules\org\eclipse\jdt\main`

I am having jar: `jasper-jdt-6.0.29`
having an ear.
but after deploying my application opens though when i check rules so drls not working.
below error i am getting..

```
/servlet/com.fourcs.clm.iwarranty.eclaims.dataview.servlets.ClaimSearchServlet
Path Info:null
Query String:null
Stack Trace:
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: compilation_beginningToCompile
    at deployment.CLMEAR.ear//org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:428)
    at deployment.CLMEAR.ear//org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:417)
    at deployment.CLMEAR.ear//org.drools.compiler.commons.jci.compilers.EclipseJavaCompiler.compile(EclipseJavaCompiler.java:405)
    at deployment.CLMEAR.ear//org.drools.compiler.commons.jci.compilers.AbstractJavaCompiler.compile(AbstractJavaCompiler.java:49)
    at deployment.CLMEAR.ear//org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.dialect.java.JavaDialect.compileAll(JavaDialect.java:405)
    at deployment.CLMEAR.ear//org.drools.compiler.compiler.DialectCompiletimeRegistry.compileAll(DialectCompiletimeRegistry.java:46)
    at deployment.CLMEAR.ear//org.drools.compiler.compiler.PackageRegistry.compileAll(PackageRegistry.java:110)
    at deployment.CLMEAR.ear//org.drools.compiler.compiler.PackageBuilder.compileAll(PackageBuilder.java:1334)
    at deployment.CLMEAR.ear//org.drools.compiler.compiler.PackageBuilder.compileRules(PackageBuilder.java:1058)
    at deployment.CLMEAR.ear//org.drools.compiler.compiler.PackageBuilder.compileAllRules(PackageBuilder.java:972)
```

I tried upgrading jar version `ecj 4.3.1` to `4.6.1` but that also not worked.

How to resolve this error. Any idea?

Answer (score -2):

If you look on the drools usage forums, you can find that Drools does not work with JDK11.
Drools 6 works with JDK7, but that version is from 2013. Latest Drools versions (7.X) work on WildFly 10 to 14 with JDK8.

Comment: This looks like a false response. I never found on Drools forum that Drools doesn't work with Java 11. Please paste those links when giving answers.